# Converting php array substr to c#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, bouncycastle, substr

I'm trying to decrypt in c#, using bouncycastle, the result of the following php code:

```
<?php
    $plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    $cipher = "AES-128-CTR";
    $key = "F5UgsDQddWGdgjdd";
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
        $plaintext, 
        $cipher,   
        $key,
        0, 
        $iv
    );
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext);
    echo $ciphertext."\n";
?>
```

in php, the following code works:

```
<?php
    $cipher = "AES-128-CTR";
    $key = "F5UgsDQddWGdgjdd";    
    $ciphertext = base64_decode( $_POST['ciphertext'] );
    $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, 16);
    $content = substr($ciphertext, 16);
    $text = openssl_decrypt(
        $content, 
        $cipher,
        $key,  
        0, 
        $iv
      );
    
    echo $text."\n";
?>
```

However, when I do the following in C# the result is just gibberish.

```
public string Test(string cipherTextStr)
{
    var cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherTextStr);
    var iv = cipherText.Take(16).ToArray();
    var content = cipherText.Skip(16).ToArray();

    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("F5UgsDQddWGdgjdd");

    IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

    cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyBytes), iv));

    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.DoFinal(content);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);

}
```

The same C# code works if I don't have to separate iv and content which makes me think that I'm either doing the initial FromBase64String wrong or the take and skip from the byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `$option = 0` to `openssl_encrypt`, the input data is PKCS#7 padded and the output data is base64 encoded. If you don't want any padding and base64 encoded output, use this option value:

```
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
    $plaintext, 
    $cipher,   
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, 
    $iv
);
```

---

Update: modify C#, manually decode the encrypted data.

```
content = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content));
```

Comment: I have no control over the php code unfortunately. I can only modify the C# one.

Comment: CTR is a streamcipher mode and does not require padding. PHP/OpenSSL implicitly disables padding for streamcipher modes. AES/CTR/PKCS7Padding in the C# code is therefore incorrect and will throw a corresponding exception for a ciphertext from the PHP code.

Comment: Switching to AES/CTR/PKCS7Padding throws the following exception: Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption

Comment: @yqit as Topaco pointed out, only an additional base64 decode is necessary.

Comment: @shingo Thanks a lot. Manually decoding the encrypted data worked. Not sure why though.